# debian keyboard key pipe not working , giving # instead.?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, pipe

I have been using virtual box Debian and am unable to use the pipe key on the keyboard(hp -British) .the pipe key gives "# " instead and "# key" gives "pound sign"?. please help
     | gives #
     # gives £
.....why? and also give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change the keyboard layout. Without the correct one for your actual keyboard, you'll experience oddities.